# how to control a running java service

Tags: java, rss, polling

I intend to create a java program/service that continuously polls rss-feeds using the informa library 'poller' functionality. I want to be able to add,delete,update the rss-url's realtime, while the program is running. I have no prior experience with the informa library but I need it to potentially scale to a lot of rss-feeds.

- Does anyone have have experience with the informa library for polling rss-feeds? What other method/libraries would you consider to poll a lot of rss-feeds (10.000+)?
- What do you consider to be an accepted solution to control a running (console) java program. I was thinking about using a control port for sending commands. Are there other mechanisms more commonly used to achieve this functionality?

Please let me know if you need more specific information.

Kind regards,
Ivo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a normal way to interact with a remote service would  be a control port as you described it.
You can also control it via Database settings and create a thread which will poll for these DBs settings. The DB settings will be set via some web? UI.

If you plan on running one service with polling on one single machine I would rather recommend against it and set your service either on virtual machines or setup multiple instances of the service on one big machine with a big amount of memory. I have been using a com.sun.syndication library for feeds parsing/retrieving.
I don't want to be a captain obvious but I think it's easily achievable with a usual multi-threading application and Concurrent Queueing. If I got you correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> What do you consider to be an accepted solution to control a running
>   (console) java program. I was thinking about using a control port for
>   sending commands. Are there other mechanisms more commonly used to
>   achieve this functionality?

1. You can read the parameter from a `.properties` file. The only disadvantage with this is that the properties file will have to be read in each time you want to use that property, irrespective of whether the value has changed.
2. You can make use of [JMX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/index.html). This is a fairly nice concept in which you expose a bean to be manageable using the `jconsole` command (Java Management Extensions Console). Once done, you can then remotely inject values into a running JVM.

There is a [nice example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/remote/jconsole.html) on <strike>Sun</strike> Oracle website that shows you how to do it.